# Customizing Facebook login and saving token to shared preferences on Android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to develop app that can post to Facebook.

So SDK is set up, I can log in using FB button like in hackbook example. 
How ever I do not really like the way it looks. I'm developing an app and then floating webview pop's up on top of it?

Maybe I'm getting it all wrong, but I'd love to get Facebook login / password somehow within my settings activity, and then save token to shared preferences.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Saving the access tokens in SharedPrefs can be done by using the following code when you are setting up a valid session.

```
Utility.fb.authorize(MainActivity.this,Utility.fbPermissions , new DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Facebook Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Dialog Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(context, "User Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Utility.editor = Utility.prefs.edit();
                    Utility.editor.putString("access_token", Utility.fb.getAccessToken());
                    Utility.editor.putLong("access_expires", Utility.fb.getAccessExpires());
                    Utility.editor.commit();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateStatus.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Cancelled by user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

And later you can just check for the validity of the access token and log in the user directly, without asking for his username or password.

```
Utility.prefs = getSharedPreferences(Utility.PREF_UTILITY_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Utility.access_token = Utility.prefs.getString("access_token", null);
        Utility.expires = Utility.prefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if(Utility.access_token != null)
        {
            Utility.fb.setAccessToken(Utility.access_token);
        }

        if(Utility.expires !=0)
        {
            Utility.fb.setAccessExpires(Utility.expires);
        }

        if(Utility.fb.isSessionValid())
        {
            //user is already logged in

            }
```

**EDIT :** Ever since Facebook API removed the offline access permission, you can increase the validity of the access tokens by putting the following code in the activity where you are doing the authentication to authorize the user login.

```
public void onResume() {    
        super.onResume();
        Utility.fb.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null);
    }
```

Comment: Tnx, I'll try it, but can I somehow "embed" it in my activity, not having it as webview that "floats" over the app?

Comment: The `Facebook API DialogListener` would always be a floating web-view if the user does not have the Facebook app installed in his phone. If the application is installed, then the web-view does not come up like that. I haven't found a way to remove the WebView when the app is not installed.